# Is there an R code or function that can help me with if statement with multiple condition

Tags: r, if-statement, multiple-conditions

I'm cleaning up my dataset which is a data frame with two columns, obtained after I joined multiple data frames. I'm trying to find a code or a logic way to tell R to create a third column using the following rules:

1. If both columns contain non-`NA` values, then the third column contains their average.
2. If one column contains a `NA`, then the third column is the value of the column without the missing value.

For example:

```
df1 <-
    data.frame(Var1 = c(34, 23, 23, NA, 32),
               Var2 = c(NA, 34, NA, 35, 55))

df1
#   Var1 Var2
# 1   34   NA
# 2   23   34
# 3   23   NA
# 4   NA   35
# 5   32   55
```

The result I want is:

```
#     Var1 Var2 Var3
# 1   34   NA 34.0
# 2   23   34 28.5
# 3   23   NA 23.0
# 4   NA   35 35.0
# 5   32   55 43.5
```

Comment: You may want to take a look into `?ifelse`.

Comment: How is this closed for opinion-based?

Comment: I have edited your question to reflect what I think it is you want, if this is incorrect please roll-back and clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need `rowMeans` here (assuming the no value as `NA`)

```
df1$Var3 <- rowMeans(df1, na.rm = TRUE)
```

If the value is above  100 or below 1, change it to `NA` (not clear about that condition) and then do the `rowMeans`

```
rowMeans(replace(df1, df1 < 1| df1 > 100, NA), na.rm = TRUE)
```